# What is the replacement of `ParameterHandler` from Vaadin6 for Vaadin7

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have to upgrade vaadin6 application to vaadin7.
The problem that I meet now is the interface [`com.vaadin.terminal.ParameterHandler`](https://vaadin.com/api/6.8.15/com/vaadin/terminal/ParameterHandler.html). It doesn't exist in vaadin7 API. In vaadin6 this interface contains the function `void handleParameters(Map)`.

In addition the function [`com.vaadin.ui.Window.addParameterHandler(ParameterHandler)`](https://vaadin.com/api/6.8.15/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html#addParameterHandler%28com.vaadin.terminal.ParameterHandler%29) isn't known in vaadin7.

So it seems that there's a new mechanism of handling parameters in vaadin7.

Does someone know this new mechanism please?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you need, but maybe this help: [Request Handlers](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.requesthandler.html). And maybe this method is useful: `VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getParameterMap();`

Comment: ParameterHandler is a vaadin6 interface implemented by class capable  of handling external parameters. What I need is its equivalent in vaadin7.

Comment: Parameters that I need are collected in Map<String,String[]> and are called: stepType, stepConfig, stepName, callbackUrl, processConfig

Comment: Maybe this: [vaadin 7 URL parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493773/vaadin-7-url-parameter). And this: `Page.getCurrent().getLocation().getQuery();`